# Doesnt work mysql search with russian lang because of case insensivity(utf8_general_ci)

Tags: php, mysql

I tried using UPPER/LOWER func in mysql query and it still didnt help... even tried to using it with mb_strtoupper/lower... My database all fields and tables are utf8_general_ci

When i type like "keyword" in russian it doesnt find anything because in database its like "Keyword" and when I type "Keyword" it shows me results

Here is my query command:
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product` WHERE `name` LIKE \'%'.$id.'%\' OR `brand` LIKE \'%'.$id.'%\' OR `manufacturer` LIKE \'%'.$id.'%\' OR `model` LIKE \'%'.$id.'%\''

Answer (score 0):

change collation to utf8-general-bin and try again.